# How to select and copy text using cypress?

Tags: cypress

I need to select the names of the whole cast; for that, I can identify the locations of the names using the CSS locators but I don't understand how can I select that text. (This is supposed be similar to the action that we perform while holding the left-mouse-button down and dragging to our desired position)

Specifically, in my case, I am trying to copy 'Ricky Gervais' and this selector takes me to it. How can I select and copy this text?

```
cy.get('tbody > :nth-child(2) > :nth-child(2) > a')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way that serves my purpose, thought i'd share it here for others to see in the future

```
         cy.get(<selector-of-the-element-that-you-want-to-copy>).then(($temp)=>{
        const txt = $temp.text()
        cy.get(<selector-of-the-field/place-where-you-want-to-paste>).type(`${txt}`+'{enter}')
```

**Important Note**

.text() is not available by default. For this, first, you need to add the following plugin

```
npm install cypress-commands
```

more information can be found at these two very useful links

https://github.com/Lakitna/cypress-commands
https://github.com/Lakitna/cypress-commands/blob/develop/docs/text.md

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Selecting plain text on a webpage can be done with plain javascript:
[Selecting text in an element (akin to highlighting with your mouse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse)

Copying the current selection to clipboard also:
[How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)